# Use external included file inside php functions

Tags: php, function

I'm writing a functions.php file...now, some functions must access the db. I have a db_connect.php file which contains the connection script. I've included it in functions.php with:

```
require "sys/db_connect.php";
```

but how to use the connection script ($con) inside

```
function a() {
   ...
}
function c() {
   ...
}
```

and so on?
I've tried already setting $con variable as global, but no success.

Comment: If `$con` was set in your `sys/db_connect.php` file, you should have access to it (assuming you are actually including that file in your script).

Comment: If it's not a global it can't be accessed in the scope of the function. @JustinWood

Comment: It also needs to be declared in global scope in the include script (which it is not implicitly). http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do this, either accessing the value using `$GLOBALS`, declaring it as a global variable or passing it as a parameter

**1st way:**

```
include 'db_connect.php';
    function a() {
        $link = $GLOBALS['con'];
        // you can assign $GLOBALS['con'] or use it as a normal variable
    }
```

**2nd way:**

```
include 'db_connect.php';
function a() {
    global $con;
    // then use it as a normal variable
 }
```

**3rd way:**

```
function a($con) {
    // use the variable
}
```

Read more about variable scopes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
function a($db) {
   //do something with $db
}
function c($db) {
   //do something with $db
}

$result = a($conn);
$something = c($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure should work. Note where the `global` declarations appear. I'd normally pass the $con variable into the function as an argument rather than using it as a `global`, though.

dbconnect.php

```
<?
$con = mysqli_connect("blah","blah","blah","blah");
?>
```

functions.php

```
require('dbconnect.php');
function a() {
  global $con;
   ...
}
function c() {
  global $con;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
// sys/db_connect.php
<?php
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>

// functions.php
<?php
require 'sys/db_connect.php';
/* you can even close the connection and reopen it this way
   $db = db(); $db->close(); $database = db(); */
function a() {
  $db = db();
}
function c() {
  $db = db();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have assigned a variable $con in db_connect.php outside any functions as follows:

```
//----------
//sys/db_connect.php
//----------
$con = 'my connection script'; //You don't need to put global here
```

Then you can use $con in functions a() and c() in another php file as follows:

```
//----------
//other_file.php
//----------
require 'sys/db_connect.php';

function a(){
 global $con;   //global allows $con from above to be used in this function a()

 print_r($con); //This line just for testing purposes!
}

function b(){
 global $con;   //global allows $con to be used in this function b()

 print_r($con); //This line just for testing purposes!
}
```